# lmfit: defining a parameter to follow a Gaussian distribution

Tags: lmfit

I noticed that one can constraint parameters in LMFIT using min, max, and /or use an expression. I was wondering if there is a way I could use an expression to constrain a parameter to follow a normal distribution defined by a mean and standard deviation. For example, one of my parameters lies between -3000 and 5000, if I specify these as minimum and maximum value, the optimizer considers them as equally likely (uniform) but instead I want it to consider values far from the mean less likely (i.e normal). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying min and max values does not actually assert equal probability for all values between these bounds. It does assert zero probability outside the bounds.

A non-linear least-squares fit as done with lmfit seeks to find the highest probability value for all parameters, it does not treat all values as equally probable.  You supply starting values for each parameter, and the method uses computed gradients (could be analytic, but typically numeric) to find the direction for optimizing each parameter value.

But if I understand your goal, you don't really want "hard wall constraints", but want to penalize the fit if a parameter is too far from the expected value.  Lmfit does not have a built-in way to easily enable this, but such penalties can be added in the objective function.  One approach is to add a "penalty" value as an added element in the array to be minimized.  That is, you can extend the residual.  Since "least-squares" a Gaussian distribution for the residual in the first place, you can simply append (`np.concatenate`) a term of::

```
(current_parameter_value - expected_value)/sigma_expected_value
```

to the residual.  In some sense, this is similar to a regularization and is sometimes called a restraint to allow but penalize values for a parameter that are far from the expected value.

Hope that makes sense!